# How to sort MySQL results alphabetically but with search term match first using CodeIgniter ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

Let say we have 4 items in a table:

1. Michel Jordan
2. Tom Mark Jordan
3. Jordan John
4. Adam Jordan Robert

The search term is "**Jordan**", how can i get the results sorted alphabetically but with search term match first like this:

1. **Jordan** John
2. Michel **Jordan**
3. Tom **Jordan** Robert
4. Adam Mark **Jordan**

Im using this code, but not getting what i want:

```
$this->db->select('id, name');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('name', $search_term);
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I think you'd have to re-sort in PHP after receiving the results. If you had the name broken up into different fields, you could get it to work.

Comment: I have the full name in one column.

Comment: Right, I understand that. Therefore, you have to get the results, then re-sort those results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, fullName 
FROM test 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET('Jordan', REPLACE(fullName, ' ', ',')), fullName;
```

Check this link [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cc0/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |          FULLNAME |
|----|-------------------|
|  1 |       Jordan John |
|  2 |     Michel Jordan |
|  4 | Tom Jordan Robert |
|  3 |  Adam Mark Jordan |
```

Comment: Looks great, but how could i use it as CodeIgniter query? And using variable $search_term instead of the word 'Jordan'??

Comment: @WaleedAsender I haven't worked on CodeIgniter so sorry for that so you have do it by your own.

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason its not working for me !!
`$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM members ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET('$keyword', REPLACE(name, ' ', ',')), name")->result();`

Comment: you are searching for `'$keyword'` you need to make sure the veriable is being inserted to the query via this:  `FIND_IN_SET('" . $keyword . "'...` that should work (true with php, im not sure with other languages)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
$this->db
     ->select('id, fullName')
     ->from('test')
     ->order_by("FIND_IN_SET('Jordan', REPLACE(fullName, ' ', ',')) , fullName");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: It keepf throughing this error:
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', `'`, `'))`, `'fullName'`' at line 3

Comment: Please make sure that you haven't used double quotes between orderby clause. Also the fullname is used without quotes

Answer (score 0):

My attempt for you:

```
$this->db->select('id, name, (SELECT name FROM users WHERE name REGEXP "^'.$search_term.'") as "regexp_match"');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('name', $search_term);
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$this->db->order_by("regexp_match", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I know it looks kinda weird, but trust me, you want to use REGEXP. :D